# How can I find the process ID of a command started in another terminal?

Tags: process, ps

If I run `sleep 30` in one PuTTY window, how can I find the process ID of the sleep command from another PuTTY window?

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Comment: @HaukeLaging - what's wrong with homework?

Comment: My brother never did his homework by himself. Now he's 28. He's still happy and unemployed:-)

Comment: @mikeserv I don't see a need to discuss why homework should not be made by others. Questions without any research effort, without any precise question but with a "do all the work for me" attitude are bad questions even under other circumstances. In a homework case Im find that embarrassing.

Comment: @HaukeLaging - don't *make* the homework. Help teach.

Answer (score 2):

### The `pgrep` Command

If your distribution has the *pgrep* command installed (e.g. from the **procps** package), then you can use the command to find process IDs by pattern. For example:

```
# Find the sleep commands belonging to the current user.
pgrep -u $LOGNAME sleep
```

This command will find all matches belonging to the current user, whether the process was started in the current terminal or another, so it will work for your PuTTY use case.

### Testing the `pgrep` Command

You can test this out on a single TTY or PTY quite simply, too. Consider:

```
$ sleep 30 & pgrep -u $LOGNAME sleep
[1] 24021
24021
```

In this example, *sleep* is put into the background and Bash reports the Job ID and PID of the backgrounded job. Then *pgrep* finds the same PID in the process list, and sends the PID to standard output. Obviously, the numbers should match.

### Multiple Matches

Note that if the current user has more than one *sleep* command running, then *pgrep* will correctly report multiple PIDs. For example, the following returns PIDs for background jobs `%1` and `%2`:

```
$ sleep 30 & sleep 30 & pgrep -u $LOGNAME sleep
[1] 24063
[2] 24064
24063
24064
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -u "your_login" | grep "sleep" | awk '{print $1}'
```